# Solr search – Tika extracted text from PDF not return highlighting snippet

Tags: solr, highlighting, apache-tika

I have successfully indexed Pdf –using Tika- and pure text –fetched from database- in one single collection. Now I am trying to implement highlighting. When I querying Solr i placing in the url the following: `http://myhost:8090/solr/ktm/select/?q=BlahBlah&start=0&rows=120&indent=on&hl=true&wt=json` . Everything is OK. The received output has the original (not highlighted text) content under “docs” and the highlighted snippets under “highlighting”. But I had noticed the documents that have been extracted by Tika don’t have “highlighting” snippet. That kind of response, cause me many troubles (zero length rows). Is there any workaround in order to tackle it? I have already tried to copyField (at index time) but the response come out blank **({“highlighting”:{}})**. I really need help on this.

Comment: I think we need some more details. How does you schema look like? How does you solr response look like (either with hl working or not)?

Comment: Hello, the response looks like: Responce header `"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":0,"params":{
      "indent":"on",
      "q":"Bloh",
      "wt":"json",
      "hl":"on",
      "rows":"3"}}`

Comment: The response: `"response":{"numFound":3,"start":0,"docs":[{"ida":"2","sea":"a","solr_id":"2_n_3889_2010","last_modified":"2012-07-31","model":"n_3889","title":"Άρθρο 14","type":"text","gri":"aaa","content":["Blah Bloh Bleh"]},{"ida":"22","sea":"Δικ","solr_id":"22_apofaseis_dikastikes","last_modified":"2012-07-18","model":"apof","title":"bbb","type":"text","gri":"bbb","content":["Lola lolo Bloh lili"]},{"ida":"45","sea":"Δικ","solr_id":"45_apofaseis_dikastikes","last_modified":"2012-07-18","model":"apof","title":"ccc","type":"bin","url":"/1.pdf","gri":"ccc","content":["Bloh Abc Cbn Cnn"]}]}`

Comment: The highlighting: `"highlighting":{
    "2_n_3889_2010":{
      "content":["Blah <em>Bloh</em> Bleh"]},
    "22_apofaseis_dikastikes":{
      "content":["Lola lolo <em>Bloh</em> lili"]},
    "45_apofaseis_dikastikes":{}}}`

Comment: Follow [link]http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-search-Tika-extracted-text-from-PDF-not-return-highlighting-snippet-td3999647.html#a3999725  . In that post i have schema.xml, solrconfig.xml and data-config.xml. Many thanks!